# Socket em C para Linux (como passar um struct?)

Tags: c, linux, socket, struct, cliente-servidor

Eu tenho uma aplicação cliente/servidor e preciso transferir um struct para o servidor, mas desse jeito não está funcionando:

```
typedef struct{
   int pontos;
   int vidas;
   int flagReiniciar;
   int flagAcabar;
   int matriz[21][19];
} dados; 


send(sockfd,&bufferDados,sizeof(dados),0);
recv(sockfd,&bufferDados,sizeof(dados),0);
```

Tem alguma forma de fazer isso? ou não tem como passar uma struct via socket?

Comment: Ahh, eu li algo sobre criar um protocolo, que seria mais interessante para mim, mas não faço a minima ideia de como fazer isso.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você não pode passar uma estrutura binária diretamente porque a máquina do servidor pode usar um processador diferente do cliente. Cada processador organiza estruturas, e mesmo tipos numéricos, de forma diferente na memória.

O ideal mesmo seria criar um protocolo, por exemplo convertendo os valores para JSON ou XML e interpretando no outro lado. Mas é possível usar estruturas binárias, seguindo algumas regrinhas:

a) as estruturas devem ser identificadas como **attribute**((**packed**)) que diz ao compilador que todos os valores devem estar grudados, sem espaçamento para alinhamento. Cada processador usa um alinhamento diferente, então desligar completamente o alinhamento remove um problema.

b) as estruturas devem usar tipos numéricos com tamanho definido (uint32_t, int16_t, etc) pois eles são os mesmos em qualquer arquitetura. Isso garante que os tipos e portanto as estruturas terão o mesmo tamanho independente de processador ou arquitetura.

c) você terá de converter todos os tipos inteiros para uma representação comum, usando htons() e htonl() na transmissão, e ntohl/ntohs() na recepção. As primeiras funções convertem o valor para big endian (padrão do TCP/IP) e as segundas convertem para o endian local. Assim, mesmo que um processador seja big endian e outro little endian, eles vão se entender.

d) É uma boa ideia ter duas versões de cada estrutura: uma para uso do programa, e outra apenas para a comunicação de rede. Apenas a segunda versão precisa ter o alinhamento desligado. Você copia os dados de uma para a outra fazendo as conversões especificadas em (c).

Um valor inteiro convertido com htonl() ou htons() não pode ser mais usado localmente, sob pena de ser tomado por um valor errado (e.g. htons(1) "vale" 256 num computador Intel). Manter os valores convertidos em estruturas usadas exclusivamente para transmissão de rede ajuda e evitar confusões.